# "Would there be an availability" vs "Is there an availability" for appointment scheduling?

Tags: grammar, phrases

It's my understanding that the first is a more formal version of the second phrase however I'm not quite certain that's the case or that they mean the exact same thing.

Comment: Frankly, both are stilted (stiff/awkward) English.  It is true that the more and more native English speakers are mistaking the use of latinate abstract vocabulary for sophistication.  “Are you available at all next week/in the coming month?” is simpler and more direct.  Or, depending on the context, “Is an appointment available some tom in the next...  whatever?”.  It would be what many think of as typically English reticence to precede what you say with “Would an appointment by any chance ...” .  Speak or write like that if you are trying to seem English!

Comment: I agree, to be honest I find myself preceding my statements while in conversation with "possibly", "probably", "might", "may", or even "I think" to insure whatever fact or opinion follows if it turns out to not be the case. But I think that doesn't make for interesting conversation and projects a low self esteem or even deceptive nature.

Comment: Yes, that’s English.

Answer (score 1):

> "Would there be an availability" vs "Is there an availability" for appointment scheduling?

Apart from being unnecessarily convoluted and non-idiomatic, the difference lies in the use of "would".

**Would** is used to soften questions and requests:

Compare

Open the window!

Would you open the window?

Have another cup of tea.

Would you have another cup of tea?

**Would** is used to soften questions and requests because it implies a tentative possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences mean the same.

But I think the first sentence sounds more pessimistic than the second one.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***WOULD***

'used in auxiliary function to express doubt or uncertainty'.

The second sentence sounds more optimistic.